# hibernate exception row was updated or deleted exception when we save answer

Tags: spring, hibernate

Here I am Providing the hibernate project code which throws the exception

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException:Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):
```

When we called the method mentioned below
i want to make this thread safe

```
public String saveAnswer(String assignmentid, String answerid, String answer) throws Exception {

        getStudentManager().logRequestedAnswer(answerid, answer);

        User user = getUserManager().getCurrentUser();

        HttpSession session = WebContextFactory.get().getSession();
        int practiceElapsedTime = getStudentManager().touchPracticeTime(assignmentid, session);
        long practiceUpdateTime = ((Date) session.getAttribute("student_current_practice_last_update")).getTime();

        StudentAnswer savedAnswer = getStudentManager().saveAnswer(user, assignmentid, answerid, answer);

        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        result.put("answerid", savedAnswer.getAnswerKey().getObjectid());
        result.put("answer", savedAnswer.getAnswer());

        //we're synching the client's time with the server on saves
        result.put("practiceElapsedTime", practiceElapsedTime);
        result.put("practiceUpdateTime", practiceUpdateTime);

        if (savedAnswer.getAssignmentStatus().isCompleted())
            result.put("progress", savedAnswer.getAssignmentStatus().getPercent());
        else
            result.put("progress", savedAnswer.getAssignmentStatus().getProgress());

        StringWriter json = new StringWriter();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(json, result);
        return json.toString();

    }
```

Comment: I presume that this problem is coming from getStudentManager().saveAnswer(user, assignmentid, answerid, answer); Could you provide this method too ?

Comment: public synchronized StudentAnswer saveAnswer(User user, String assignmentid, String answerid, String answer) throws Exception {

  if (user == null || user.getStudent() == null)
   throw new GeneralSecurityException("Permission Denied");

  Auditor auditor = new Auditor(user);

  AssignmentStatus status = getAssignmentStatus(user, assignmentid);

Comment: StudentAnswer studentAnswer = getStudentAnswer(user, assignmentid, answerid);

Comment: Object oldStatus = auditor.clone(status, new AssignmentStatus());
  //Object oldAnswer = auditor.clone(studentAnswer, new StudentAnswer());
  Object oldAnswer = auditor.clone((studentAnswer == null) ? new StudentAnswer() : studentAnswer, new StudentAnswer());
  Date now = new Date();

Answer (score 1):

There are two things i learned with hibernate.
First, if you save the same object multiple times rapidly you may have a StaleObjectStateException. This is due to versioning on the table. A simple solution is to disable it.
You should consider locking too if your table is accessed by multiple threads: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html

Answer (score 0):

It probably means the row you are trying to update has already been updated by some other thread before your transaction is getting committed. Check whether the same record is being handled by multiple threads simultaneously.